# jquery how to get data from API xml

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, api

I need to get data from an API which returns xml format. here's the api url: http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&lines=all&format=xml

here's my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.get('http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&lines=all&format=xml', function(d){

                    $(d).find('line').each(function(){
                        var $line = $(this).find('name').text()
                        var $mex = $(this).find('message').text()
                        $('#status').append($line+'<br>'+$mex+'<br><br>');
                    });
                });
            });
```

The div #status returns empty. My jquery code seems fine because with a physical xml file it works. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Mauro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't fetch XML cross-domain like this, you'll have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json#JSONP) if the server supports it. XML has to be fetched via an XMLHttpRequest...which is blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Unfortunately, it doesn't *look* like that site supports JSONP, though it does support regular JSON: http://api.tubeupdates.com/?method=get.status&lines=all&format=json

Comment: ok, so will it work if I use json to fetch the data? Sorry my ignorance, I'm pretty new to this :)

Comment: @Mauro74 - nope, it has to be JSONP, which basically creates a `<script>` tag, looking at the documentation and testing myself...it doesn't seem there's any hint of support for this: http://tubeupdates.com/documentation/ The author of that site will have to add it, or you'll have to proxy the request through your own site.

Comment: @Nick ok I'll try to contact the author of the api to see if he could add JSONP. Anyway I have no idea on how to proxy the request, any good tutorial/advice on this? Thanks :)

Comment: @Mauro74 - depends which platform you're on, what do you have server-side? PHP, ASP.Net, ruby, other?

Comment: I'm using PHP as server-side language

Comment: @Mauro74 - here you go, Yahoo has a nice write up and code for PHP: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$` from this variable line and add:

```
var line = $(this).find('name').text();
var mes  = $(this).find('message').text();
$('#status').append(line + '<br/>' + mes + <br/>);
```